# Email Compare Product List

Tags: magento-enterprise

How to add the function to forward "compare product list" via email with a form?

I tried to look for an extension but no luck.

Thanks,

Comment: You mean you want to send the compared product list via email?

Comment: @MagePsycho jup, I think so. Quite interesting feature actually

Answer (score 3):

To do this properly write your own module, a tutorial about that you can find here on [Tutsplus.com](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643).

First we'll add a form to the product compare popup. Add the following to your modules layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_compare_index translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="share.form" after="-" template="[namespace]_[module]/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_compare_index>
</layout>
```

Create the `[namespace]_[module]/form.phtml` file in the template directory

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('[namespace]/email/send');?>">
    recipient name <input type="text" name="name" value=""/><br/>
    recipient email <input type="text" name="name" value=""/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

Now we'll need to create an email layout. We can use the compared product list template and block.

The template itself needs some tweaking tho, copy it to your own folder.
It needs some stuff getting stripped like everything outside the table and the add to cart URLs which won't work from an email.

`[namespace]_[module]/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml`

```
<?php $_total=$this->getItems()->count() ?>\
<table class="data-table compare-table" id="product_comparison">
    <?php $_i=0 ?>
    <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
            <col width="1" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <col width="<?php echo floor(100/$_total); ?>%" />
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="product-shop-row top">
        <?php $_i=0 ?>
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <td>
                <a class="product-image" href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-top') ?>
            </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $_attribute): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                    <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_attribute->getStoreLabel() ?></span></th>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <td>
                    <?php switch ($_attribute->getAttributeCode()) {
                        case "price": ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-' . $_attribute->getCode()) ?>
                            <?php break;
                        case "small_image": ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" />
                            <?php break;
                        case "date":
                            echo substr($this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute),0,10);
                            break;
                        default: ?>
                            <div class="std">
                                <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute), $_attribute->getAttributeCode()) ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php break;
                    } ?>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

We can now add this new template with the original compared product blocks to your modules layout XML layout node

```
    <compared_products_email_items>
        <block type="catalog/product_compare_list" name="catalog.compare.list" template="[namespace]_[module]/catalog/product/compare/list.phtml"/>
    </compared_products_email_items>
```

The email template will call this block

```
<!--@subject  {{var store.getFrontendName()}}: Check out these coompared products @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",
"var name":"Receivers name",
"layout area=\"frontend\" handle=\"compared_products_email_items\"":"Compared Products Items",
"var comment":"Invoice Comment"}
@-->
<!--@styles
@-->


{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Dear {{var name}}, look at these products.
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{layout area="frontend" handle="compared_products_email_items"}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
```

And we'll add this email template to the modules `config.xml`

```
<global>      
    <template>
        <email>
            <[namespace]_[module]_email_template module="[namespace]_[module]">
                <label>Share compare email</label>
                <file>share_compare_email.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </[namespace]_[module]_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
```

Now we'll need a controller that actually sends this email to the email address in the form. Inchoo wrote [a nice article about custom emails](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/) we'll use.

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_EmailController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function sendAction()
    {
        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('[namespace]_[module]_email_template');                                    

        $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('recipient_name');
        $email = $this->getRequest()->getPost('recipient_email');

        /*
         * send the email
         */
        $emailTemplate->send($email,'name, [
            'name' => $name
        ]);
    }
}
```