# How to send compare product list via email in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, email, compare

I want send compare product list via email in magento 1.9. i have tried this link [Email Compare Product List](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97471/email-compare-product-list) but not works for me. following is my list.phtml file

```
<?php

<div class="page-title title-buttons" id="compare-title">
<img id="compare-logo" src="http://skin/frontend/sm_market/default/images/logo.png">
<h1 class="compare-title"><?php echo $this->__('Compare Products') ?></h1>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="window.print(); return false;" class="link-print button"><?php echo $this->__('Print This Page') ?></a>

</div>
<div class="comparison-div">
<?php $_total=$this->getItems()->getSize() ?>
<?php if($_total): ?>
<table class="data-table compare-table" id="product_comparison">
<?php $_i=0 ?>
<?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
        <col width="1" />
    <?php endif; ?>
        <col width="<?php echo floor(100/$_total); ?>%" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<thead class="fixedHeader">
        <tr class="fixed-tr">       
    <?php $_i=0 ?>
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                <th id="compare-head">Product Name</th>
            <?php endif; ?>
             <th class="name">
     <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
              </th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>        
        </tr>
            </thead>    
<?php if ($_total>2): ?>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <?php $_i=0 ?>
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                <th id="compare-head">&nbsp;</th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <td class="a-right"><b><a href="#" class="btn-remove" onclick="removeItem('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getRemoveUrl($_item) ?>');" title="<?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Remove This Item') ?></a></b></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
   <?php endif ?>   
    <tbody>
        <tr class="product-shop-row">
        <?php $_i=0 ?>
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
                <th id="compare-head">Product Image</th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <td>
                <a class="product-image" href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="#" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->getProductUrl($_item) ?>', true)" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_item->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-top') ?>
                <?php if($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <ul><li class="add-to-links"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" id="comapre-addto-cart" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>', true)">                        
                    <span class="addcard-text"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                    </button>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>

                        <li class="wishlist-li">                                
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-wishlist button" id="wishlist-comparison" onclick="setPLocation(this.href, true)"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $_attribute): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
            <th id="compare-head"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_attribute->getStoreLabel() ?></span></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <td>
                <?php switch ($_attribute->getAttributeCode()) {
                    case "price": ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-' . $_attribute->getCode()) ?>
                        <?php break;
                    case "small_image": ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'small_image')->resize(125, 125); ?>" width="125" height="125" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" />
                        <?php break;
                    case "date":
                          echo substr($this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute),0,10);
                          break;
                    default: ?>
                        <div class="std">
                            <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $this->getProductAttributeValue($_item, $_attribute), $_attribute->getAttributeCode()) ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php break;
                } ?>
            </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
            <tr class="add-to-row">
            <?php $_i=0 ?>
            <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <?php if($_i++%10==0): ?>
            <th id="compare-head">&nbsp;</th>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <td>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true, '-compare-list-bottom') ?>
                <?php if($_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <ul><li><button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" id="comapre-addto-cart" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setPLocation('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>', true)">                        
                    <span class="addcard-text"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                    </button>
                <?php else: ?>
       <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
                <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>

     <li     class="wishlist-li">                               
     <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item);?>" class="link-wishlist button" id="wishlist-comparison" onclick="setPLocation(this.href, true)"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<div class="buttons-set">
    <button type="button" id="product-comparison-close" title="<?php echo $this->__('Close Window') ?>" class="button" onclick="window.close();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Close Window') ?></span></span></button>
    <span class="please-wait" id="compare-list-please-wait" style="display:none;">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Please wait...') ?>
    </span>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    decorateTable('product_comparison');
    function removeItem(url)
    {
        new Ajax.Request(url, {
            parameters: {isAjax: 1, method: 'POST'},
            onLoading: function(){$('compare-list-please-wait').show();},
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                $('compare-list-please-wait').hide();
                window.location.reload();
                window.opener.location.reload();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
<?php else: ?>
<script type="text/javascript">window.close();</script>
```

someone knows answer please share. please help.

Comment: Is there need to develop module? please answer. i am new in magento.

Comment: anybody knows answer please help. your help will be appreciated.